# add_column error with data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the add_column function within the tibble package to add a column or two to my `df` data frame, but I keep getting different errors based on how I try to manipulate the arguments of the function. `df` is a 60 x17 data frame. Here's the code that I currently have tried so far:

Try 1:

```
library(tibble)
add_column(Depth +.5 =df[1], .after = 1)
```

Try 2:

```
library(tibble)
add_column(df, depth + .5 = rep(df[1], nrow(df)), .after = 1)
```

I want the new column to be inserted after column 1 in `df`, and I want the newly created column to say "Depth + .5" and to be filled with data from my `df[1]` column. (I'm going to alter the values in it later), but I need the row values to be adaptable for when I import different data sets of different lengths, which is why I'm trying to do it as `df[1]` since its length is going to change depending on the data that I import. Also,  I'm not sure if I need to put "Depth + .5" in quotes or what in order to make it work, but that's what I'd like the column to say/be named at the top.

Comment: I would seriously advise you not to use that column name. It will ba a pain in all subsequent work... however if you insist...`add_column(mtcars, `depth + .5` = mtcars[,1], .after =1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two key points: one, you need to include `df` in the add column function. Second, I see where you were going with your `rep` line, because you were getting an error about number of rows needing to match. However, all you need to do is reference the existing column (which is already the correct length) and perform your operation. To do that we just use `df$Depth`, or you could use `df[,1]`.

```
add_column(df, 'Depth + .5'= df$Depth + .5, .after = 1)
```

Comment: I ran that updated line of code you provided and got the following error: "Error: `.data` must have 60 rows, not 0"

Comment: Check that `df` still has all its data in it, and that you didn't overwrite it by mistake.

Comment: This is the exact same line of code using `mtcars` and it runs fine: `add_column(mtcars, 'Depth + .5' = mtcars$mpg +.5, .after=1)`

Comment: it still has all of its data in it. The mtcars example works on mine too, but mine doesn't. I'm stumped and not sure what to do